# install4j remove uninstaller script at uninstall

Tags: install4j

Due to install4j not having a maintenance installer in order to allow the removal of just some of the components I have modified the uninstaller to create configurable form displaying each uninstallable component and then simply delete the files based on user selection which in turn meant the removal of the standard Uninstallation screen.

From what I remember, when using the Uninstallation screen every file (if added by installer) is removed, including the JRE and the uninstall script itself.

Is there any way to achieve just the removal of the JRE folder and the uninstall script without using the full Uninstallation screen?

This is for a Linux installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File uninstallation is not done by the "Uninstallation" screen but by the "Uninstall files" action. The JRE is also removed by the "Uninstall files" action. There is no way to delete the JRE but with the "Uninstall files" action.

If you have a partial uninstallation mode, you can set a condition expression on the "Uninstallation" screen or the "Uninstall files" action so that it only runs if full uninstallation is selected.

Comment: I have created an action "Delete files and directories" inside "Uninstall files". This is removing all the folders except JRE. It is not able to delete the JRE folder because Un-installer is using it.